# different behaviour between ipython and python shell for importing paraview

Tags: python, ipython, python-import, paraview

I'm trying to use paraview (http://www.paraview.org/) with python scripting in IPython.

When I'm trying to use it in a python shell it works just find but when I'm trying in IPython I've got the following error:

```
>>> import paraview.simple
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/gaspard/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-2.2.2/platforms/linux64Gcc/paraview-3.12.0/lib/paraview-3.12/site-packages/paraview/simple.py", line 39, in <module>
import servermanager
File "/home/gaspard/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-2.2.2/platforms/linux64Gcc/paraview-3.12.0/lib/paraview-3.12/site-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 43, in <module>
import paraview, re, os, os.path, new, sys, vtk
File "/home/gaspard/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-2.2.2/platforms/linux64Gcc/paraview-3.12.0/lib/paraview-3.12/site-packages/paraview/vtk/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from vtkCommonPython import *
ImportError: libvtkCommonPythonD.so.pv3.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>>
```

The command I used were:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/gaspard/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-2.2.2/build/linux64Gcc/paraview-3.12.0/bin/')
sys.path.append('/home/gaspard/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-2.2.2/platforms/linux64Gcc/paraview-3.12.0/lib/paraview-3.12/site-packages/')
import paraview.simple
```

Do you know why I've got a different behavior between the classic python shell and the IPython console? And how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point to the directory `/home/gaspard/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-2.2.2/platforms/linux64Gcc/paraview-3.12.0/lib/paraview-3.12/`.

Comment: Thank you! And I explained the different behaviour between the iPython console and the python shell by the way I was lauching the ipython Console (with gui), as it is said here: (http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2012-January/009340.html)